# Adding a title in Custom Graph in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I using a custom graph api for publishing a story. While publishing the story the API always picks up the "One to One - Without Object Title" and not "One to One". I need to pick the "One to One" as it has an option to update the "level.title".

### Question

1. How to make my code to pick "One to One"
2. How to correct my post to have "
   James Jack cleared a level 1 in Puzzle Game - Ball Mania" Instead of "James Jack cleared a level in Puzzle Game - Ball Mania"

[image]

### Code

```
    // Create an object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "puzzlegameballmania:level")
            .putString("og:title", "Puzzle Game - Ball Mania")
            .putString("og:image", "http://i67.tinypic.com/svl2qt.png")
            .putString("og:url", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=memory.game.collection.free")
            .putString("og:description", "Color of the balls matters more. Lets break the goal and go higher !")
            .putString("puzzlegameballmania:level:title", "LEVEL 1")
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("puzzlegameballmania:clear")
            .putObject("puzzlegameballmania:level", object)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("puzzlegameballmania:level")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(AndroidLauncher.this, content);
```

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code, and not just screenshots of it.

Comment: @CBroe I have added the code

Comment: I don't think you are formatting your object correctly. First of all, the title of your object should be Level 1 and not the game name. Also where did you get this `.putString("puzzlegameballmania:level:title", "LEVEL 1")` from? I would also try this differently (just for testing) by having a custom property under your level object called, for example, `lnb` and then your sentence will look like `bla cleared level {level.lnb} in appname`